# How do I fetch/pull multiple branches matching a wildcard string?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

Goal:
I have several repositories that are managed by the same rules. I would like to create a git alias to help fetch and/or pull only the relevant branches without fetching information for lots of remote branches relating to work I do not care about. I hope the end result will keep my log output clean and manageable while still giving my relevant information.

Specifics:
I would like a single command to pull "master" and any branch starting with "development/" (i.e. development/2.0...). There are several other branches that I would like to avoid fetching. These typically take a form beginning with "integration/" or "personal/".

What I got:
I now know what git Porcelain is thanks to a comment in "git fetch --help" and here is how I use it:

```
git fetch origin master:master -u
```

This even works to get master and 1 development branch:

```
git fetch origin master:master development/2.0:development/2.0 -u
```

But I am having troubles scaling it to every development branch without listing them individually (this appears to do nothing):

```
git fetch origin development/*:development/* -u
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: The `development/*` stuff *should* work, provided your command interpreter does not eat or otherwise mangle the asterisks.  Note that the usual local branch names are the "remote tracking" branches, `refs/remotes/<remote>/...`, not your local branches, so that looks a bit odd.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/20452710/6309

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know that you can do this on the command line but you could do it by configuring the refspec in your git configuration.

Config normally looks something like this.

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = .....
```

You would want something like this I think (untested)

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/development/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = .....
```

Though the fetch lines from that might possibly need to be more like these but I'm not sure

```
    fetch = +refs/heads/development/*:refs/remotes/origin/development/*
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: Took me a couple tries before I realized this needed to be in the individual repository config and not my global git config.

    fetch = +refs/heads/development/*:refs/remotes/origin/development/*
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master

Does exactly what I want. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: How about deleting the block that you said untested? So the next reader just got the straightforward answer.