# SourceTree - how to checkout to remote repo branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, sourcetree

I create a new branch in remote GIT repository. Repository stored on BitBucket.

In my my local repository I can see this new branch with SourceTree. It appears in commits list, on same commit I create branch from. But I cannot see this new branch under branches list and cannot checkout it.

I want to checkout and push updated on my local workstation code to remote repository back, but within exactly this new branch. I started development on same branch, what was source to clone new branch.

I tried to pull this new branch. It is empty as it should, but it still not under branches list and I cannot checkout it.

How to commit to this new branch?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

With [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) (1.9.6.1) alone (not talking about the command-line here), make sure:

- you have fetched the repo
- your log view is set to "All Branches" (*not* "current branches")
- "Show Remote Branches" is selected

Note: the `BRANCHES` section at the left side of the log view only display *local* branches, not the remote ones.
The remote branches are list in the `REMOTES/origin` section, just below `BRANCHES` and `TAGS`.

By double-clicking on the remote branch, you can create a new local branch.

[image: checkout new branch from remote tracking branch]

Comment: Looks like this should help. I have no idea about remote branches are under origin, so was not able to checkout any of them. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like this is no longer there in SourceTree v2

Comment: @K48 I am with SourceTree 2.5.5 very latest edition (June 2018) and I see exactly what I described in the answer (when double-clicking on a remote branch which is *not* the one currently checked out)

Comment: Note to self: this is my 400th Guru badge.

Comment: finally an explanation of this in Sourcetree, thanks!

Comment: While I found that you COULD do this on REMOTES > origin I found that REMOTES > origin (scroll through hundreds/thousands of branches to find the one I want to check out) to be a more than a bit painful - I could see no way to "type and filter somehow:" using the UI there. (vers 3.3.8)

Comment: When I try to Check Out in Sourcetree from our bitbucket server Sourcetree just crashes

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I suspect you would need to change the local repo [refspec](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44333437/6309 in order to [fetch *less* branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20450003/6309, making the remote selection and subsequent checkout possible.