# Does git fetch <remote> fetch it for all the local branches tracking that remote?

Tags: git

If I have multiple local branches tracking a remote branch `foo`, does

```
git fetch foo
```

fetch foo for all the local branches that track it or just the one I am in at the time of the fetch?

IOW, if I switch to another branch that tracks the same remote, do I still need to fetch the remote after I did it immediately before in the other branch?

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-to-fetch-all-git-branches) that is remotely related but I think it means that the `--all` in `git fetch --all` means fetch all remotes and not fetch the one remote the current local tracks for all the local branches it tracks.

Comment: @Andreas seems to have understood it well...

Comment: right but that was not so clear.  i needed an answer and Andreas provided it.

Comment: `git fetch foo` fetches branches from the remote named `foo`... If you have one... Or if `foo` is a group of remotes, it fetches from all of the remotes in that group. Otherwise it prints an error message and exits..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have several local branches tracking the same one then `fetch` will fetch for all of them, or the one, as it's really just one remote branch.

Say your remote branch is `devel` then it will be named `origin/devel` locally and all your local branches will track `origin/devel`, the one and only.

So for your local branches you only need to do `git rebase origin/devel` after a `git fetch origin` to have it updated. All local branches will have it's upstream at the exact same commit.

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered and accepted but I'll add this anyway: `git fetch remote` takes everything the named *`remote`* is willing to give you based on the "refspec" arguments.  With no refspec, it uses the refspecs given in `fetch =` lines for that particular remote.

The default refspec, if you have not configured any, is:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

assuming the name of the remote is `origin` (which is also the default, usually).<sup>1</sup>

You can think of the two git sessions (yours, doing `git fetch`, and the one on the remote that supplies data) as having a sort of telephone conversation.  Yours calls up theirs and asks it for a list of all its references, and the SHA-1 IDs that go with them.  Theirs might say "I have branch master and branch devel" (with some SHA-1s) "and tags v1.0 and v1.1" (with more SHA-1s).

At this point, your `fetch` goes through the list they gave you and picks out the names and SHA-1s it wants.  They will go through some more conversation as needed, to select all the underlying repository objects needed to complete the objects that go with those SHA-1s ("commit" SHA-1s need "tree" SHA-1s which need more trees and/or "blobs"; but you may already have some, most, or all of them).  Then they send over all the SHA-1-identified repository objects, and your fetch stashes them in your repo.

Finally, your fetch updates *your* copy of *their* reference-names, using those same refspecs.  With the standard one for `origin`, this means that each of their branches—each name under `refs/heads/` in *their* repository—gets a corresponding name in *your* repository, but listed under `refs/remotes/origin/` instead.  So your repository now has every branch they had when the "phone conversation" started, but in your repo, these are listed as a "remote branch" under `origin/`.

If you already have the name, `fetch` needs to know what to do if the associated SHA-1 has changed.  For instance, their `refs/heads/master` might point to a different commit SHA-1 now.  There are special fast-forward rules for branches,<sup>2</sup> but the main thing to know is that the `+` at the front of a refspec means "forced update": the `+` in `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` means "update them all, no matter what".  Without the `+`, some reference-names may be left pointing to the original reference.

If you add `--tags` to your `git fetch`, this has the effect of adding `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` to the refspec set.  This brings over all tags—into your (single, global) tag namespace under `refs/tags`—but *without* forced-update, so that if you already have a tag like `amphibient-save`, *their* tag with the same name will be ignored.  (If your Git is 2.19 or later, see VonC's footnote; I have not tested this yet.)

This boils down to: "by default, git fetch brings over all branches and all useful tags".  However, the specifics are useful to know, especially in edge cases.

---

<sup>1</sup>There is a special hack for `tags`: if you have not specifically asked your `fetch` to bring over all tags, but you *have* asked for branches—again, this is the default—it looks to see which, if any, tag references go with branches you're bringing over, and your `fetch` then updates your tags with those tags, as if you'd listed `refs/tags/tag:refs/tags/tag`.  As with `--tags`, this is a "non-forced" update.

<sup>2</sup>Non-forced tag updates used to follow the non-forced branch update rules of allowing the update if and only if the update is a fast-forward.  This behavior changed as of git version 1.8.2; tags now update only if forced, regardless of fast-forward.

Comment: "their tag with the same name will be ignored.": This will need to be re-evaluated with Git 2.19. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51918981/6309